# Windows 8.1 shutdown does not work for log-off

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, cmd.exe, logout

I am experiencing the following issue on my Windows 8.1 laptop. When I go to cmd and type

```
shutdown -s -t 60
```

then it works fine and message about planned shutdown is displayed.

However, if I type

```
shutdown -l -t 60
```

then it just displays the shutdown command help menu and nothing else. I tried to log-off from `cmd` using shutdown on two other PCs (Windows 7, Windows Server 2012), and the same problem occurs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `-t` is "the time-out period before *shutdown*" and `-l` is *logoff*.  Since you are logging off (with `-l`) instead of shutting down, `-t` is not valid, and so the help is shown to you.

The help just doesn't mention that.

Perhaps check out this related SU question for some ideas on implementing a delay before logoff:

- [Windows 7 Command Line Timed Log Off](https://superuser.com/questions/631239/windows-7-command-line-timed-log-off)